# how can I get a specific element in json with python

Tags: python, json, api, google-books

I want to access a specific element with python, but I can't

```
import json
import requests

search_book = str(input("search a book: "))
request = requests.get("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=" + search_book)
request_text = request.text

data = request_text
print(data['items']['volumeInfo']['title'])
```

the mistake is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/ddvit/Documents/programming/python/books/books.py", line 9,
>   in 
>       print(data['items']['volumeInfo']['title']) TypeError: string indices must be integers

Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: This is ot python this is text

Answer (score 1):

You taking raw text from response, use `json()` method instead:

```
import json
import requests

search_book = str(input("search a book: "))
response = requests.get("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=" + search_book)
data = response.json()
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the rseult as JSON you need to either load it `json.loads(request.text)` or retrieve directly with `request.json()`

Then items is an array, so you can't access the info directly,

- you may iterate on it, then get the title

  ```
  data = request.json()
  for item in data['items']:
      title = item['volumeInfo']['title']
      print(title)
  ```
- access one directly

  ```
  print(data['items'][0]['volumeInfo']['title'])
  ```